# FIRMessagingDelegate causing Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, segmentation-fault

I'm using Swift 2.3, if i add this extension :

```
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

}

Xcode fail with:

> Swift Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault

I've tried clean/rebuild project , derived data and restart XCode (8.0)

Comment: From the Answers Section by @DamienC. : Same problem with Swift 3 / XCode 8. We can also find this issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/98)

Comment: I've upgraded  cocoapods to 1.0.1 version and all seems to work